# Close current form and open new form and then return

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to click button and go to FormSetting, and close current FormMain. When I'm done working on FormSetting, I want to click the back button and go back to FormMain.

```
//FormSetting
private void ButtonSetting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    FormSetting formsetting = new FormSetting();
    formsetting.SetPrevForm(this);
    // OpenSeconderyForm(formsetting);
    formsetting.ShowDialog();
}


//FormMain
public void SetPrevForm(Form f)
{
    formMain = f;
}


private void toolStripButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    formMain.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: The code is somewhat confusing (try to provide a [repro]), but it looks like all you need is something like `this.Hide(); using (var frm = new FormSetting()) { frm.ShowDialog(); this.Show(); }`

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a main form and a settings form. When the settings form is shown, your code is attempting to hide the main form. When the `Button8` on the `ToolStrip` in your settings form is clicked, your code tries to close the settings form and make the main form visible again. I will offer a few basics and you can modify them to your requirements. So let's start with minimal representations of your two forms:

[image: show either the main form or the settings form]

---

**Clicking the [Settings] button**

The "trick" here is that when you call `ShowDialog` for your settings form, pass the `this` keyword. That will set the `Owner` property of your settings form to point to the main form.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    private void buttonSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _settings.ShowDialog(this);
    }
    SettingsForm _settings = new SettingsForm();
}
```

---

**Hiding the main form when the settings is shown**

By overriding the `OnVisibleChanged` method *in your settings form*, the visibility of the main form can now be manipulated using the `Owner` property. When `Button8` is clicked, it closes the settings dialog which causes the `Visible` property to change to `false`. The `OnVisibleChanged` override will detect this so that the main form can be made visible again using the `Owner` property.

```
public partial class SettingsForm : Form
{
    public SettingsForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Visible)
        {
            Owner?.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            Owner?.Show();
        }
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    }

    private void toolStripButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Close();
}
```